# Как обновить таблицу значением из другой и все это JOIN третьей

Tags: mysql, sql

**table1**
[parent] [value1] 
**table2** 
[name] [value2] 
**table3** 
[name] [parent]

известно значение name

```
UPDATE table1 
JOIN table3 ON table1.parent = table3.parent 
SET table1.value1 = "хочу сюда присвоить значение table2.value2 
в котором table2.name = table3.name"
WHERE table3.name = "vasia"
```

Comment: так сделайте еще join с table2

Comment: @Mike как записать правильно, не пойму

Comment: `UPDATE table1 
JOIN table3 ON table1.parent = table3.parent JOIN table2 on table2.name=table3.name SET value1=table2.value2 WHERE table3.name = "vasia"`

Comment: @Mike я могу только читать из table2 или обновлять тоже, в раздел SET можно еще добавить  table2.value2 = "3"?

Comment: обновляться может только 1 таблица